# C Language: When you dereference a "pointer to a pointer to int", what is supposed to be returned?

Tags: c, pointers

Let's say you have:

```
    void *a = //some address;
    *((int **)(char*)a) = 5
```

I'm not really clear on what the second line is supposed to be doing... I know that 'a' is casted to a pointer to a char, and then eventually casted to a pointer to a pointer to an int, but it was unclear what dereferencing a pointer to a pointer to an int actually does...

This would be very helpful. Thanks

Comment: Where are you getting your questions from? Is this homework?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it is storing the value 5 in "some address", but more precisely, it is storing the value 5 widened to the machine address size in those many bytes starting at "some address".

e. g. if it is a 64-bit machine, it is storing the value 0x0000000000000005 at the 8 bytes starting at "some address"

i don't see why it is doing it in such a complicated way, but who are we to judge the intentions of a programmer hard at work at the end of a long day.

Comment: Agreed, assuming that on this implementation, the conversion from `int` to pointer type (in particular `int*`) is as expected. Formally, it's UB to convert `5` to a pointer type even if you don't ever dereference that pointer-to-what-we-think-is-address-0x5. In practice implementations do something that's predictable if you know anything about the architecture.

Comment: But there have in the past been implementations that take advantage of the fact that `int` has a certain alignment, to leave the bottom bits out of `int*`, and so `5` could end up stored as `5/2` or `5/4`, perhaps with stuff in the top bits to indicate memory bank or other such junk. No such stuff really happens on the flat-memory architectures we're used to, though.

Comment: @Steve: it's implementation-definied, not undefined; the whole point of the introduction of `intptr_t` was to add a portable way for well-defined conversions between integer and pointer types

Comment: @Christoph: The conversion is implementation-defined, but creating the pointer value is undefined unless there actually is an object located at the address that results from converting `5` to pointer type (the nominal one-past-the-end-of-an-array would be good enough). That's possible, but pretty unlikely. Using a dangling pointer value (other than a null pointer) is UB, and writing the pointer value to memory is using the value. The intuition is that an implementation may trap if a pointer register ever holds an invalid value, although of course the standard doesn't go into specifics.

Comment: Basically, `intptr_t` is specified to allow you to take a valid pointer, convert it to an integer type, and then later convert it back to its original type. It *doesn't* allow you with defined behavior to convert an arbitrary integer value to pointer type, although of course any flat-memory implementation will in practice let you do just that.

Comment: C99 6.3.2.3 §5: _"An integer may be converted to any pointer type. Except as previously specified, the result is implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned, might not point to an entity of the referenced type, and might be a trap representation."_  That's all the standard says, as far as I can tell. Basically, the cast in itself is safe but if the pointer now points into lala-land, bad, implementation-defined things may happen.

Answer (score 1):

If you dereference a pointer to a pointer to an int you'll get a pointer to an int. Dereferencing means you'll get the object it was pointing at which is in this case a pointer to an int.

Here's an interesting article that explains [how to interpret more complex declarations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1x82y1z4.aspx)

Comment: surely you mean "you'll get a pointer to an int", probably typo when you said pointer to a char

Comment: "which is in this case a pointer to an int." aka, "an address to an int", right?

Comment: @Jacob, pointers and addresses are very different things.  a pointer is a variable, i. e. a memory location, that can contain any value you assign to it.  an address is a constant that cannot be changed.  (think over it a bit).

what is confusing you is the declaration "void* a = ..." -- this does NOT mean you are changing the address of a.  all you are doing is assigning a value to a.  the "void*" is just the type declaration for a.  so read it as just "a = ..."  specifically read the "void* a = (void*)5;" as "a = 5;"  the rest of the stuff is type-information which is used later. contd.

Comment: @Jacob, (contd.) the type information of a variable that is a pointer is used when you use the value stored in the pointer variable.  say a pointer variable `a` contains the value `888` and then you say `*a= 7` that means you want to write the value 7 in the memory location 888. the ambiguity that remains is whether you want to write 7 in the single byte at address 888? or as an integer into the 4 bytes starting at address 888? or as a long integer into the 8 bytes starting at address 888? this is where the type of a is used. if a is declared as `char* a`, just 1 byte, if `int* a`, 8 bytes...

Comment: Ah, I see. So when we say that a pointer "points to an address", it is equivalent of saying that it "stores that address", as in 'a' will store that address, right? (and then a* will store something *in* that address)

Comment: correct @Jacob (although you probably meant that a pointer "points to a variable", it is the equivalent of saying that it "stores the address of that variable")

Answer (score 0):

It's a nonsense, obfuscated way of writing:

```
void* a = (void*)5;
```

As we can tell, original code doesn't make any sense. Here is what it does:

- Assign an address to a.
- Typecast a from void pointer to char pointer.
- Wildly typecast the char pointer to a pointer-to-pointer to int.
- Take the contents of the pointer-to-pointer, ie the address where an int should be stored.
- This address will be stored where a currently stores its address, overwriting it with the address 5.

EDIT: Btw, note that implicit integer to pointer casts are not allowed in C (C99 6.5.4 §3). There must be a cast like in the code above.

Comment: So we've essentially said that the address of 'a' is now 5? Does this conflict with agks's explanation?